# Attach additional info to Lambda time-out message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

When a Lambda times out, it outputs a message to CloudWatch (if enabled) saying "Task timed out".

It would be beneficial to attach additional info (such as the context of the offending call) to the message. Right now I'm writing the context to CloudWatch at the start of the invocation - but it would sometimes be preferable if everything was contained within a single message.

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no almost-timed-out-hook. You may however be able to inspect the context object you get in the Lambda handler to look at the remaining run time and if it gets close to timing out printing out the additional info.

In python you could use `context.get_remaining_time_in_millis()` as per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html) to get that info.

Answer (score 1):

There is no **timeout hook** for lambda but can be implemented with a little bit of code

```
    import signal
    
    def handler(event, context):
        ....
        signal.alarm((context.get_remaining_time_in_millis())
        .....
    
    def timeout_handler(_signal, _frame):
        raise Exception('other information')
```

We implemented something like this for a lot of custom handlers in cloudformation.

Comment: Interesting - haven't heard about `signal` before. Is `timeout_handler` guaranteed to trigger before the execution is terminated?

Comment: it must because we are building on (context.get_remaining_time_in_millis() -2 ) . So we just have 2 seconds to execute our custom code to run anything we want to.

Comment: here is the example: https://gist.github.com/toddlers/6db02c642ec2d0eecc0c0c781bfb8aee