# AWS Lambda : invoke a method before lambda termination(timeout)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda `eventFetcher` which calls external API to get the data and sends the response to `SQS`.
The API call happens in a loop until the response keeps returning the data.
The problem is the data is so huge that it is taking more than `15 minutes(900s)` to complete the transaction.
Is there any `hook` or `lifecycle` method which I can attach to the lambda so that it gets called before the lambda is terminated? (in that `hook`, I want to perform some cleanup activities like closing the open connection, etc).
Any other alternative is also appreciated.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such hook or lifecycle event. But it is something that you can relatively simply **implement yourself**.

Since your function iteratively is checking for completion of your API call, you can **measure execution time** in each iteration and when you will be close to 15 minutes, then you can send notification to a dedicated **SNS topic**.

Alternatively, you could use [SQS dead-letter queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html) for your SQS. If message failed to be processed by your lambda function, it will go to DLQ. This could trigger other process/lambda function which would do all the clean up for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to answer the same in this question [Attach additional info to Lambda time-out message?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65427698/2246345).

Below is an example:

```
    import signal
    import logging
    import time

    LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
    LOGGER.setLevel(logging.INFO)


    def handler(event, context):
        # Setup alarm for remaining runtime minus a second
        signal.alarm((int(context.get_remaining_time_in_millis() / 1000) - 1))
        time.sleep(10)


    def timeout_handler(_signal, _frame):
        print("handle the timeout here")
        raise Exception('Time exceeded')

    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)
```

And the corresponding log:

```
    handle the timeout here
    [ERROR] Exception: Time exceeded
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 13, in handler
        time.sleep(10)
    File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 19, in timeout_handler
        raise Exception('Time exceeded')
    END RequestId: 7792ab80-20bc-4759-8613-088511b7c933
    REPORT RequestId: 7792ab80-20bc-4759-8613-088511b7c933  Duration: 1002.68 ms    Billed Duration: 1003 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 48 MB  Init Duration: 119.91 ms
```